# Execution failed while running a Kotlin module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am getting following error in Build Output when running a Kotlin module :-

```
Execution failed for task ':Test:compileKotlin'.
> 'compileJava' task (current target is 1.7) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The build.gradle file for this module has the following code:-

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Kindly help me find the error and its resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make java version 17 not 1.7 like this:

```
plugins {
id 'java-library'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

java {
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```